# Should we change the Privilege levels for the site?

Tags: discussion

The privilege level's seem to be fairly low to me, it doesn't look like it will take long to get a lot of users onto the higher privileges that could potentially open the site up to users damaging the site. Should we change those levels?

The current levels are: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Compare that to the Stack Overflow levels: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The privilege levels are set to a lower level during the private beta to help bootstrap the community while you build up enough reputation to perform those tasks. The privilege levels return to "normal" as a site passes from private to public beta, and then again when it graduates.

[**Reputation requirements compared**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160292/98786)

Comment: Awesome - thanks!